# Stopping event propagation - salesforce1

Tags: javascript, mobile, salesforce

I have a `Javascript` mobile app that had an initial problem of touch down resulting in refreshing of the page. To counteract that, I added a `ontouchmove` attribute on my div tag where in the javascript I stop propagation (`event.stopPropagation()`)

Context of the screen :

Asks a simple question, with 4 radio button options, and 2 buttons. The two buttons are being cut off after I've stopping the propagation. Confused how the bubbling of parent tags are impacting my buttons being cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

Share the code so that everyone can better understand the problem.
From your statement above I could infer that some event which was vital for your screen has also stopped because of your stopPropagation call.
stop propagation should be the last resort, rather you can add your event to a specific component or add class to all components for which you need to listen to the event so as to avoid bubbling on the whole screen.